# Find indices of specific rows in a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for a way in numpy to find the indices of outer specific rows in a 3d array. One example would be to find all occurrences of a given set of colours in a RBG image, and fetch the pixel coordinates.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row) shows that the `in` operator can behave weirdly with arrays, and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927475/numpy-array-get-row-index-searching-by-a-row) lead closer but works for 2D arrays.

Let's say we have the 3d array `Z` with dimensions `(x,y,z)`, and `[s0, s1]` the 3rd dimension rows we want to match.

```
Z = np.zeros((10,20,3), dtype=int)
s0 = np.array([1,2,3])
s1 = np.array([4,5,6])
Z[1,2] = s0
Z[4,5] = s1
```

I want all `(x,y)` where `z` is equal to either `s0` or `s1`.

So far,
`argwhere` return every match where one element from `s0` is in `Z`:

```
> np.argwhere(s0 == Z) 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2]])
```

`in1d` return a boolean 1D array with True where element in s0 or s1 match:

```
> np.in1d(Z, [s0,s1])
```

and if I try the raveled way:

```
> Zravel = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[-1]).ravel()
> np.all(np.in1d(Zravel, [s0, s1]) == False)
```

all element are `False`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) would flatten its inputs. So, you can feed it `Z` and a stacked version of `s0`, `s1`, giving us a boolean array that could be reshaped into an array of the same shape as `Z`. Then, you need to check for all TRUE rows in it for the matching indices. The implementation would look like this -

```
S = np.row_stack((s0,s1))
out = np.where((np.in1d(Z,S).reshape(Z.shape)).all(2))
```

You can also use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to solve it like so -

```
out = np.where(((Z == S[:,None,None,:]).all(3)).any(0))
```

If you would like the output stacked in an array -

```
outarr = np.column_stack((out))
```

For creating `S`, you can replace `np.row_stack` with `np.concatenate`, which might be faster, like so -

```
S = np.concatenate((s0,s1)).reshape(-1,s0.size)
```

Sample run -

```
In [145]: Z = np.zeros((10,20,3), dtype=int)
     ...: s0 = np.array([1,2,3])
     ...: s1 = np.array([4,5,6])
     ...: Z[1,2] = s0
     ...: Z[4,5] = s1
     ...: 

In [146]: np.where(((Z == S[:,None,None,:]).all(3)).any(0))
Out[146]: (array([1, 4]), array([2, 5]))

In [147]: np.where((np.in1d(Z,S).reshape(Z.shape)).all(2))
Out[147]: (array([1, 4]), array([2, 5]))

In [148]: np.column_stack((np.where(((Z == S[:,None,None,:]).all(3)).any(0))))
Out[148]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])

In [149]: np.column_stack((np.where((np.in1d(Z,S).reshape(Z.shape)).all(2))))
Out[149]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: so the trick is to inflate the S object to dimensions that will match Z for broadcasting?

Comment: @toine Yup! So how many such s0, s1.. would you have? If it's just two :  s0 and s1, you won't need broadcasting at all! I just assumed a generic case to solve for i.e. S would store s0, s1, s2, s3 and so on.

Comment: I'll have more as you guessed : ) so that solution looks good.

Comment: @toine Awesome! So just add those in the first line. Also,  you can replace `np.row_stack` with `np.concatenate` for squeezing out more performance.