# Numpy return index of subarray into array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Looking into this related question:

[Numpy Array Get row index searching by a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927475/numpy-array-get-row-index-searching-by-a-row)

I would like to know if there is a method without loops that would return an array of indexes of where each row of array y is located within array x.

Here is an example:

```
x= np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]])
y = np.array([[0,1],[0,3],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]])
```

The desired output should be:

```
[0,2,3,6,7,8]
```

y array will never have any duplicates, and all elements of y will be located within x. Since I am working with big arrays (in the order millions of elements), using any loop solution is not feasible. This is the reason why I am looking for a "numpy command", if it exists, that does the trick.

Comment: Using `%%timeit` with an array of 60 elements and a subarray of 12 elements, approach 1 gives 76.1 µs ± 561 ns per loop, approach 2 gives 84.4 µs ± 2.42 µs per loop and approach 3 gives 54.1 µs ± 548 ns per loop.