# Retrieve column index in 2d numpy array from the value of this column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

If I have two numpy arrays like:

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
b = np.array([ 0, 4, 8])
```

and I would like to get the index of the column of *a* that corresponds to the values of *b*. Here it would be 0.

With something like:

```
np.where(np.hsplit(a, 4) == b)
```

I'm able to find the solution but I think it should be some more intuitive way of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18927811/8321904).
The only difference is that you need to transpose `a`.

```
>>> a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> b = np.array([ 0, 4, 8])
>>> np.all(a.T==b,axis=1)
array([ True, False, False, False])
>>> np.where(np.all(a.T==b,axis=1))[0][0]
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is more or less intuitive, but you can transpose `a` and compare:

```
np.where( (a.transpose() == b  ).all(axis=1))
```